# Create unique value from now()?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In excel I am creating some unique customer ids, I thought the following formula would work, however it creates the same id's each day.

```
= "M" & INT(NOW()) + ROW()
```

Is there a way in excel to get the current time as an integer (like Unix time from epoch) so every id will be unique?

My formula always results in the same ids each day:

```
M43782  
M43783  
M43784  
M43785
```

Comment: NOW() is volatile and will update every time Excel recalculates.  It will not stay stagnate.  If you want it to remain stagnate you will need vba.

Comment: @ScottCraner is there a different variable I can use to get a timestamp (accurate to the millisecond)?

Comment: A formula will not do what you want.  It will need to be code in vba.  Formula are live and will change as the input changes.

Comment: @ScottCraner the unique ids are generated then exported to CSV (where they become static values, ie, `= "M" & INT(NOW()) + ROW()` forever becomes `MXXXXX`) to be imported into an ERP. So as long as my formula can grab the timestamp accurate to the millisecond this will work - aslong as there is a formula/excel variable that can give me a timestamp accurate to the millisecond, are you aware of such a variable?

Comment: NOW() will do the millisecond but it is live and all will be the same.  Each cell will not have a different time.

Comment: @sazr ,, you may think for `= "EMPL00" & ROW()` ,, if written in ROW 1 it may `="EMPL00"&ROW()-4` if at Row `5`,,, or share with us if any set pattern you do have or if ID is based on certain value.

Comment: @sazr,, **Cont,,** or you may think for `="EMPL"&INT(MOD(L$12,1))+ROW()` if at `Row 1` or if at `Row 5` then `="EMPL"&INT(MOD(L$12,1))+(ROW()-4)`, where `L2` has `DATETIME`  value.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solutions 3 (circular reference) and 4 (VBA) provided in the attached link should solve your question:

[How to Insert a Timestamp in Excel [Formula + VBA + Shortcut]](https://excelchamps.com/blog/timestamp/)

VBA seems the smoothest way because do not rely on a client setting.

Comment: You may go with this also,, `="M" &INT(L$2)+ROW()` where `L2` has `DateTime` value.